# JSGrid Callback Methods

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building grid using *JSGrid* (js-grid.com). I want call back methods to implement validations before adding new record or updating record. Documentation provided on website is not clearly mentioned how to implement one. Please refer http://js-grid.com/docs/#callbacks.
I need help how can i implement callback method cause i am new to JSGrid & Scripting. Following is my sample code. Please guide me where to put callback methods.

```
    $(function() {

    $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
        height: "90%",
        width: "100%",

        filtering: true,
        editing: true,
        sorting: true,
        paging: true,
        autoload: true,

        pageSize: 15,
        pageButtonCount: 5,

        deleteConfirm: "Do you really want to delete the client?",

        controller: db,

        fields: [
            { name: "Name", type: "text", width: 150 },
            { name: "Age", type: "number", width: 50 },
            { name: "Address", type: "text", width: 200 },
            { name: "Country", type: "select", items: db.countries, valueField: "Id", textField: "Name" },
            { name: "Married", type: "checkbox", title: "Is Married", sorting: false },
            { type: "control" }
        ]
    });

});
```

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: what about `onOptionChanging`?

Comment: http://js-grid.com/docs/#oniteminserted

http://js-grid.com/docs/#onitemupdating

http://js-grid.com/docs/#onoptionchanging

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {

$("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
    height: "90%",
    width: "100%",
```

// added for demo

```
onItemInserting: function(args) {},  // before controller.insertItem
onItemInserted: function(args) {},   // on done of controller.insertItem
onItemUpdating: function(args) {},   // before controller.updateItem
onItemUpdated: function(args) {},    // on done of controller.updateItem
onItemDeleting: function(args) {},   // before controller.deleteItem
onItemDeleted: function(args) {},    // on done of controller.deleteItem

    filtering: true,
    editing: true,
    sorting: true,
    paging: true,
    autoload: true,

    pageSize: 15,
    pageButtonCount: 5,

    deleteConfirm: "Do you really want to delete the client?",

    controller: db,

    fields: [
        { name: "Name", type: "text", width: 150 },
        { name: "Age", type: "number", width: 50 },
        { name: "Address", type: "text", width: 200 },
        { name: "Country", type: "select", items: db.countries, valueField: "Id", textField: "Name" },
        { name: "Married", type: "checkbox", title: "Is Married", sorting: false },
        { type: "control" }
    ]
});
```

});